# How to change GPG password prompt from GUI dialog to minibuffer?

Tags: gpg, prompt, passwords

I am using `mu4e` mail client for `Emacs` which when opened asks for my `gpg` password to decrypt the file containing my email's password, but it always shows a GUI dialog box. I want it so `Emacs` asks for this password in minibuffer instead. I have installed `pinentry` package and set `epa-pinetry-mode` to `loopback`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  (use-package pinentry
    :straight t)

  (setq epa-pinentry-mode 'loopback)
  ;;  (setq epg-pinentry-mode 'loopback)

  (pinentry-start)
```

Do I have to make some other tweak to make this work?

I also have added this line in `gpg-agent.conf` file inside `gnupg` directory,

```
allow-emacs-pinentry
```

NOTE: I have my `GNUPGHOME` environment variable set to `~/.local/share/gnupg`, could this be an issue?

Comment: My setup is similar, but I'm using `epg-pinentry-mode` instead of `epa-pinentry-mode`. It seems that you tried both, since one of those is commented.

Comment: `epa-pinentry-mode` [was renamed](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/3af9e84ff59811734dcbb5d55e04e1fdb7051e77/etc/NEWS.27#L1909) to `egp-pinentry-mode`, so that's the same package. `pinentry` was [removed from `Emacs` core](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/3af9e84ff59811734dcbb5d55e04e1fdb7051e77/etc/NEWS.26#L1415) as not necessary since `GnuPG >= 2.1`. See [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-01/msg00233.html) discussion.

Comment: @aadcg Yes, I tried both, neither seems to work. Could you share your setup if you have something different from mine?

Comment: @Y.E.Yea so I heard.